# Spring boot ,a Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use by tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to run a new project using Spring boot.

The port 8080 is used by Tomcat, and when I release the port using TASKKILL and restart the server, I get the same message - Tomcat takes this port first and the web server fails to start.

Comment: I have observed that sometimes spring boot shows an error like port is already in use. However at the same time when I scrolled up in the error logs, I realized that the actual error was different. So when I solved that error the port error got solved  as well. So please check your full logs in case you are also having that. Because Springboot won't start double servers in one go by default.

Comment: restart your machine and problem will solve if you getting this message after even killtask process

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the server port by adding this line in your `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8090
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to click on the double cross button (Remove All Terminated Launches) and the red square button (Terminate) as given in below picture, after this your application will run on the same port.

[Terminate & Remove All Terminated Launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqMfj.png)

Or you can change the port with the help of below line in application.properties

```
server.port=<Port Number>
```

Comment: there is no image

Answer (score -1):

we should enter the application.properties
server.port=8087

Comment: Welcome! There is an earlier answer with the same content. Please check previous answers before creating a new one.